# reduce the number xlabels in a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a huge dataset which I'm processing using `lualatex`. (Normal compilation runs out of memory). The data cannot be sampled as it has some spikes (see figure). So I use the whole dataset. For the x-axis how do I tell `pgfplots` to display only few entries. Obviously I cannot use `symbolic x coords`. Is there a way around?

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, transform shape]
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 1 by 1, vertical sep=2cm},height=7cm,width=1.0\textwidth]
        \nextgroupplot[title=foo,ylabel={Cost},xtick=data]
                \addplot[brown, semithick,mark=square]      table{data/foo.dat};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Comment: regarding your comment that you cannot resample your data: I had similar problems once with some spikes in my dataset. I usually have my data in Matlab and export it and I solved the problem by resampling while considering a threshold condition in the x- as well as in the y-direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `xtick=data`, use some thing like `xtick={0.5,1,1.5}`. Change the values as you like.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0, transform shape]
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 1 by 2, vertical sep=2cm},height=7cm,width=1.0\textwidth]
        \nextgroupplot[title=foo,ylabel={Cost},xtick={-6,-5,...,5,6},]
                \addplot[brown, semithick,mark=square]  {rnd};
        \nextgroupplot[title=foo,ylabel={Cost},xtick={-6,-4,...,4,6},]
                \addplot[brown, semithick,mark=square]  {rnd};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. I used `xtick={1.31,...,1.55}`. The label started with `1.31` but it never ended. So it ended up with only 1 label.

Comment: @arunmoezhi: Try `xtick={1.33,1.35,...,1.50,1.55}`